# Using global variables declared in C, in Arm assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I have a C file which declares a global variables. This file will be compiled together with some ARM assembly files.

```
int foo;

void call_asm(void);

int main(void) {
    call_asm();
    return foo;
}
```

```
call_asm:
    ...
```

I tried using the [link from the arm infocenter](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0203j/Cihcciij.html) but the compiler (`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`) is telling me that "import" is an undefined instruction.

Can I simply do something like:

```
LDR    r0, =GLOBAL_VAR
```

How can I use the global variables defined in the C file in assembly?

Comment: you should accept your answers or provide comments.

Comment: GAS assumes that all undeclared symbols are external by default.  Yes, you can just use `ldr r0, =foo` to get the address into `r0`.  (Assuming a platform that doesn't prepend `_` on C names.)

Comment: Andy Polyakov has a technique in OpenSSL for this use case. Checkout the translated code for [`sha1_armv4.S`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/sha/asm/sha1-armv4-large.pl) (and friends), and how `OPENSSL_armcap_P` is handled. (The linked code is the Perl source; it needs to be translated per [Cryptogams SHA](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Cryptogams_SHA)). However, I was experiencing *"unexpected reloc type 0x03"* in a shared library. I needed to gut `OPENSSL_armcap_P`.

Answer (score 4):

This becomes quite simple once you ask gcc how to do it. For example, compile the following function with `gcc -S -O3`:

```
extern int foo;
void useFoo()
{
    foo=7;
}
```

You'll see how gcc implements it.

Based on this, I've devised a working example of calling an assembly function from C to set a global C variable:

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

void setupFoo();
int foo;

int main()
{
    setupFoo();
    printf("foo=%d\n", foo);
}
```

```
# test.s
.text
.global foo
.fooAddr:
    .word foo

.global setupFoo
setupFoo:
    ldr r0, .fooAddr
    mov r1, #123
    str r1, [r0]
    bx lr
```

Compilation and running:

```
$ gcc test.c test.s -o test && ./test
foo=123
```

Tested on gcc Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1.

That assembly code above was based on the gcc output for the `useFoo` example. A simpler way is to use `=foo` instead of manually placing the address to a variable:

```
# test.s
.text
.global foo
.global setupFoo
setupFoo:
    ldr r0, =foo
    mov r1, #123
    str r1, [r0]
    bx lr
```

This will result in the address of `foo` being put after the function definition by the assembler.

Comment: Or depending on assembler options, the `ldr r0, =foo` pseudo-instruction might expand to `movw`/`movk` to construct a 32-bit address from two 16-bit immediates.

Comment: @PeterCordes what options can make GNU assembler do this?

Comment: @Ruslan: I don't know.  Probably gcc only does it at the compiler level, for `-mcpu=cortex-a53` or something, so GAS might never do it.  Clang's built-in assembler might know about `-march` / `-mcpu` options, though.  Or maybe no assemblers ever do this, and `ldr reg, =constant` is always a load.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to translate the directives from the ARM assembler to the GNU assembler. If I understand correctly, you can access any global symbol by using the `.global` directive instead of `.import`. From the [Using as](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/as/index.html#Top) pages:

> *.global **symbol***
>
> .global makes the symbol visible to ld. If you define *symbol* in your
>   partial program, its value is made available to other partial programs
>   that are linked with it. Otherwise, *symbol* takes its attributes from a
>   symbol of the same name from another file linked into the same
>   program.

Answer (score 2):

```
.extern (symbol)
```

is what you need